# push notifications in enterprise accounts

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, certificate

I am working in a company,which has an app which they want to publish as an in-house app, using an enterprise account, after uploading the .pem file in order to start receiving push notification to the device, the server error was as following:

```
... GeneralException, "message":"Unable to connect: tls:\/\/gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195:2 (stream_socket_client()": SSL operation failed with code1 ...
```

any idea what the error is? is it from the certificate or from the server?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on our experience and development scenarios a regular enterprise push notification can be easily sent with an enterprise (or in-house) development account.

Below is a quick guide to configuring the enterprise developer portal for development (beta) and distribution push notification. Just the enterprise guidelines to keep in mind.

First of all, some proof that we are actually talking about an In-House dev account:
For this issue please create a new AppID in the dev portal at Apple. At the bottom, you can see the checkbox for “Push Notifications”. Check it and Submit
When submitted it gives a green sign, indicating that Push is enabled for this AppID.

After that, you can see that for this AppID (still in-house) push can be configured. Just like with regular APNS. Then you can download the push certificate and use.

For more details you can go on to the link shared below :

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html